# Number of ordered trees of size $n$

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I'm trying to solve a problem related to counting the number of trees.

Basically, I want to count trees as different only if they have different structure. So, for example, there are $5$ trees of size $4$, let them be:
 $A, B, C, D, E$:

```
(A) (B)  (C)  (D)    (E)
 *   *    *    *      *
 |   |    |\   |\    /|\
 *   *    * *  * *  * * *
 |   |\   |      |
 *   * *  *      *
 |
 *
```

Notice that trees $C$ and $D$ are different because on $C$, the first child of the root has a child, whereas on $D$ the second child of the root does. Also, notice they are not necessarily binary trees.

Is there a formula to find the number of such trees for any given number of nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such trees are in fact called ordered trees (perhaps you were thinking of labeled trees?) and the number of such trees is given by $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{n} {n \choose k} {n \choose {k-1}}}.$$
For more information see this paper: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachumd/papers/Enumerations.pdf

Comment: No, that's not right. There are only $4$ rooted trees of size $4$, because $C$ and $D$ are considered the same.

Comment: @Anonymous Oh right, I'll edit my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah, I got ordered and labeled trees mixed up. I'll edit the question.